# Submit is not a function in a FormPanel api

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, websphere-7

I have been following the [ExtDirectSpring form posting](http://code.google.com/p/extdirectspring/wiki/FormPostMethod) guide closely. I defined an `api` with `load` and `submit` functions on a `FormPanel`. `load` function works as expected, but `submit` shows "submit is not a function" when debugging in Firebug.

I've checked for buttons named "submit", but haven't found while looking at the source code.

ExtJS 4 is used with Spring 3 on a WebSphere Portal 7 server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.form.Panel` is just a container for actual `Ext.form.Basic` component.
Use `FormPanel.getForm().submit()`

Comment: Following the guide mentioned, I wrote `var myform = new Ext.form.FormPanel(...)` and then called `myform.getForm.submit()`. It still doesn't work as expected. Also, why would load work as expected if I forgot `˛getForm()`?

Comment: `myform.getForm().submit()`. `getForm()` is a method not an object

Comment: `load()` works as expected, becuase it's a method of `Ext.form.Panel`. See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel

Comment: I forgot parentheses. Naturally, `myform.getForm().submit()` was called.

Comment: do you still get `submit() is not a function` or something else?

Comment: Yes. Here's the detailed output: `me.form.api.submit` is not a function
[Break On This Error] `me.form.api.submit(formEl, callback, me)`;

Comment: I forgot `@Controller` annotation. I will accept your answer anyway.